# local development mode rails Geocode connection because of expired certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

A `User` model has a method
  `after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present?  }` as required for the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) .

However, the moment the server launches the action

```
 OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `admin_update'
```

which is coherently pointing to the command to update the record (validation has passed, so object can save).

```
 @user_object.update!(user_params)
```

The local machine has an older system (OS X 10.9.5).  The keychain was updated for ISRG Root X1 and X2 certs.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
```

How can this process be run with the proper cert?

Comment: Can't you update your local openssl? Locally you could 
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Comment: attempting to update to 1.1.1l failed for a `'CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h' file not found`  error.  The process to `sudo make install` for 1.0.2u did run smoothly, however `openssl version -a
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg` is still stuck on the older version.  Please expand on your suggestion - where can that be edited?

Comment: Scratch that.  found a posting that suggested placing that in an initializer.  Soundly: `if Rails.env.development?  require 'openssl' OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  end` to handle the local testing and development phase only.

Comment: did you find a way to fix this? I have a similar issue there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70853629/sslerror-certificate-has-expired-while-using-httpi

Comment: for development and test modes, the previous comment worked.  The  issue is with the rbenv-build  `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" rbenv install 3.1.0`  allows to use the homebrew built openssl library that you specify.